# How to read a text file and scan for a name in PHP?

Tags: php, replace

There are two files on my server,

1. balance.php
2. balance.txt

balance.txt file contains following data;

```
jhon==>20000==>present
tom==>50000==>present
karissa==>55000==>present
ryan==>25000==>present
bob==>45000==>present
```

PHP script is, scan for username and once username found (explode is used), add 10000 to its balance amt (next to username);

```
<?php

$user = "bob"; //searching for bob
$salary = 10000; //want to add 10K in his balance

$scan = fopen("balance.txt","w+");
while (!feof($scan)) {
$eachline = fgets($scan);
$eachline = explode ("==>",$eachline);

if ($eachline[0]== $user){
$oldAmt = $eachline[1];
$newAmt = $oldAmt + $salary;

echo "Username  : ".$user;
echo "Old Amount: ".$oldAmt;
echo "New Amount: ".$newAmt;

\\Now write $newAmt in place of $oldAmt, in balance.txt file.
\\HOw can I do this in easy way?
}
}
fclose($recon);
?>
```

Now, replace $scan[1] with $amt. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest/safest method is to use a temporary file, e.g.

```
$in = fopen(...); // original file
$out = fopen(...); // temporary file
while($line = fgets($in)) {
   ... do math ...
   fwrite($out, ...);
}
fclose($in);
fclose($out);
rename($temp, $original);
```

Doing in-place edits on the file is VERY tricky, especially if the length of what you're editing changes. e.g. consider

```
bob==>500==>present
```

you add 500, and end up with

```
bob==>1000==>present
```

which is exactly 1 character longer. If you replace the original line with this new longer line, you'll have overwritten the first char of the name on the NEXT line with the `t` in present.

Comment: Thank u so much. This is the easiest trick i have ever seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to write the contents of `$scan` back to the file would be using [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) in collaboration with implode.

```
file_put_contents("balance.txt", implode($scan));
```

Comment: which then kills the original file. OP is reading line-by-line, and you'd be overwriting what was there.

Comment: Basically what I ment was rewrite the line, put ALL the lines back together and write it back to the file.

Comment: yes, but file_put_contents will replace the ENTIRE file, not just the one line being edited.